# Where are themes stored?

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5

Where KDE Plasma 5 themes are stored?

Answer (score 6):

According to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/3f6opj/plasma_5_where_are_themes_installed_to/), you want to check:

- `/usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/`
- and `~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/`

Keep in mind that if you browse to the directories with a graphical file manager, `.local` will be hidden.

Comment: What's the difference between those two directories?

Comment: @GalGrünfeld when theme is installed in `/usr/share` then it is available to all user of the system. when it is installed in `~/` it is available only to the user who installed it

Answer (score 2):

According to [Plasma Themes and Plugins](https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/plasma/):

> **Global Theme** (formerly called Look and Feel) can switch a panel layout, Icon Theme, Plasma Style, etc. It also contains the splash screen on login, and the lock screen.
>
> - System/Default `/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/`
> - User Installed `~/.local/share/plasma/look-and-feel/`

This is likely what you are looking for.